# Trying to switch between std::cout and std::ifstream

Tags: c++, ifstream, cin

I want to read inputs from either `std::cin` or `std::ifstream` which are determined from the command line. The command looks like `./run 1` or `./run 2`. Right now, I have to write two almost similar functions based on the read mode.

```
void read1()
{
  int a, b;
  while (std::cin >> a >> b) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

or

```
void read2()
{
  int a, b;
  std::ifstream fin("file.txt");
  while (fin >> a >> b) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

For big  loops it is difficult to maintain both functions since the loop part is common and the only difference is input source.

How can I integrate the two functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::cin` and `std::ifstream` are both `std::istream`s, so you could solve this problem by using a function that operates on a reference to `std::istream`. This would work in `std::cin`, `std::ifstream` instances, and any other `std::istream`s:

```
void read(std::istream& input)
{
  while (input >> a >> b) { .... }
}
```

then switch on the caller side.

```
if (something)
{
  read(std::cin);
} else
{
  isfream input(....);
  read(input);
}
```

Comment: I think you should point out that this works because both std::cin and std::ifstream are std::istream

Answer (score 0):

both std::ifstream and std::cin are inputstreams, you can call the function with a istream as argument